# Ajax retaining information when opened in new tab or reloaded

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm creating a website which i need to retain information when placed in another tab or page is refreshed.

Here's the part of the code where i need to retain the information.

```
$(".dev").append(lines[i]+"\n");
```

lines[i] are ip addresses that will be listed in my textarea.

```
<textarea class='dev' cols='50' rows='10' readonly='readonly' style='resize:none;'>
```

Now how can i retain the information from my textarea when opened in new tab or browser is refreshed? I've used memcache before but i don't wanna use that i need to do it in ajax or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LocalStorage.  They work like similar to cookies.

Here is a nice article on LS use:
http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/04/how-to-use-html5s-local-storage-tools-today/

But, in short, you would save the info like a cookie:

```
myjsobj={
  one : 1,
  two : 2
}
localStorage.setItem('mylist',JSON.stringify(myjsobj));
```

and retrieve it like so:

```
myRetrievedObject=jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem('mylist'));
```